# customer receives SSL from an unknown source

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

We have a customer who is logging in to our website and receiving an `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. It turns out when the customer is logging in to our app they receive an SSL that isn't coming from us. At first it was for the domain `*.adperfect.com` and later `*.ni.a1q7.net` (both of which we are not familiar with). We use AWS cloud, our routes are handles through an ALB and our certificates also though AWS. No other customer is experiencing anything like this.

This happens to the customer on chrome, in incognito mode too, when using a different browser, even when using the phone with data internet not just their wifi. They swear they didn't install anything fishy, and clearing cache or data does not matter. All of this looks extremely suspicious but honestly I can't really tell what might be going on here. How does something like this even happen? Customer is insisting this only happens when they try to log in to our service and no one else's. I'm willing to believe we having something misconfigured but how and why would that ever mean sending a completely random ssl certificate that we do not have boggles my mind.

Any ideas on what this might be? Anyone encounter something like this before?

Comment: This is probably a MitM, either a "legitimate", albeit badly configured SSL termination by their ISP, or a real Man in the Middle attack. As your customer to use a different Internet Link - either with their 4G hotspot or using another ISP altogether.

Comment: they claim it happens with their 4G hotspot too

Comment: Do they maybe use an IDS or IPS which does TLS inspection and is injecting a certificate for tls inspection?

Comment: @Turdie I don't think so. Also wouldn't that affect any website they visit?

Comment: Yes could be affecting

Comment: @Turdie customer is saying it only happens when logging in to our app, so I don't think it's that.

Comment: Also is possible let one of the their it staff do `openssl s_client -connect adperfect.com:443` and see what comes up. This way you exclude browser cache out of it and so on. Also ask them to do developer tools trace when they visit the site, a har file https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/10358597?hl=en

Comment: `I can't really tell what might be going on here. How does something like this even happen?` it happens all the time. You aren't going to resolve this by chatting "sounds fishy". Where is their IT support and why aren't you discussing it with them?

Comment: Ask them to send you a traceroute from their ISP to your IP.

Comment: @GregAskew I told the customer to talk to their IT support for their computer, however since the issue happens when they try to log in specifically to our site, naturally the customer approached us, so I'm trying to figure out why it's happening

Answer (score 0):

You don't "receive an SSL" - you are presented with a (TLS or x509) certificate.

> At first it was for the domain *.adperfect.com and later *.ni.a1q7.net (both of which we are not familiar with)

Have you checked they are the *only* users impacted by this? More specifically, have you tested this outside of your current networks?

> We use AWS cloud

Which is a shared resource so it *might* be a configuration issue at the remote end. The first domain is (at least partially) hosted on AWS. Can't find any names for the latter.

ASSUMING that they are the only people impacted by this, then your first step is to check they see same DNS records as everyone else. Running `nslookup yoursite.example.com` will tell you and them what the name resolves to. It would also be a good idea to get the impacted customer to send you a copy of the certificate they are presented with, just in case they are using some ropey MITM anti-malware product.

You should also check the ALB configuration.

Comment: I did ask them to run nslookup on our domain, which showed a list of IPs. One of them is recognizable as ours, the other two I'm not sure about, however I'm not sure how relevant that is. Our ALB is connected to an ASG with several instances that sometimes get replaced, so the IPs change and The ALB logs don't contain information about which IP address it sends clients to (not that I see), so I'm not sure these are wrong per se

Comment: It's a safe assumption. We have many clients, but not that many and our CS team is in constant contact with our clientele. It's a very hands-on business, and our customers are noisy. It's hard to imagine anyone else having an issue like this and not complaining.

Comment: for the IP's you don't recognize, open a https session towards them with your browser and inspect the certificate.

Comment: They also might be hacked and their /etc/hosts files have a hardcoded entry pointing your domain to a man in the middle host trying to steal credentials.

Comment: "or the IP's you don't recognize, open a https session...." is enough for a drive by attack. Given there is already some bad smells here, that would be a bad idea unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

It might be some issue with your DNS resolution, as...
both domains you listed are also AWS Route53 domains:

```
$ host -t ns adperfect.com
adperfect.com name server ns-1304.awsdns-35.org.
adperfect.com name server ns-1893.awsdns-44.co.uk.
adperfect.com name server ns-240.awsdns-30.com.
adperfect.com name server ns-934.awsdns-52.net.
$ host -t ns ni.a1q7.net
ni.a1q7.net name server ns-1405.awsdns-47.org.
ni.a1q7.net name server ns-1852.awsdns-39.co.uk.
ni.a1q7.net name server ns-264.awsdns-33.com.
ni.a1q7.net name server ns-736.awsdns-28.net.
$
```

Maybe there's a typo in the IP of the Name resolution?

Comment: how can I verify this? how would this even happen?

Comment: as per your comment on the answer from @symcbean you see IPs you don't recognize in the resolution of your own domain, I'd start by removing those.

Comment: You could ask your customer to clear their DNS cache. Macos: ```sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder```, Windows: ```ipconfig /flushdn```.

Comment: yeah but just because I don't recognize them is not necessarily meaningful as the IPs for our app constantly shift. I will try asking the client to run that macro see if it helps although I'm doubtful